# Clarification on WW 2 US Army Discharge Papers (General Orders)

Tags: world-war-two, ww2-european-theater, historical-research, army

I am attempting to do some research on my paternal grandfather whom served in WW2.   He was honorably discharged in AUG 46 and I have a copy of that paperwork.  I know he served as a part of the 26th Infantry Division and was in the 101st Infantry Regiment

I am attempting to get clarification for the following line(s):

31# Military Qualification And Date

**CIB GO 9 101 INF MAY 45**

I *think* this means:

- “CIB GO 9 101 INF MAY 45” Aaward of the Combat Infantryman Badge (CIB) to a member of the 101st Infantry in May 1945.
- GO 9 *should* refer to General Order 9

However, I found the following online
https://mcoecbamcoepwprd01.blob.core.usgovcloudapi.net/library/GeneralOrders/DAGO1945.pdf

And I see nothing related to this award under GO_9 (Page 1107/1163) and it also reads that this GO is 10 Feb 1945.

So my questions are as follows:

1. Have I read this line correctly in that this was an award of the CIB under General Order 9 in May of '45
2. If that's the case, am I looking at the wrong document?
3. Am I just totally going down the wrong direction on this one?

I've attempted reaching out to the Archives in St. Louis but like so many the records were lost in the fire.  So all I have are a few photos, two news paper articles, and his discharge paperwork.

TL;DR - Can someone explain what CIB GO 9 101 INF MAY 45 is

Comment: You are looking at the War Department general orders, a CIB would not be included as those were promulgated at the regimental level on the basis of time on the line or wounds received while serving as an infantryman in an infantry unit.  Your GO 9 is a 101st Infantry Regiment order, not a War Department order.  At the regimental level these CIB awards are usually just a list, sort of "the following soldiers are awarded the Combat Infantry Badge:" followed by the list of names, ranks, and service numbers.